# "Lexical and PreProcessor issue" error in IOS when use XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, github, youtube

I'm newbie, I want to build an app that allow user to play youtube video. Then I try to use this framework [XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController). I try to run their demo but it Failed. The compiler inform this error :

```
 Demo-Prefix.pch:14:10: 'XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h' file not found
```

I already added the file "'XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h" to project but it still failed. I'm newbie this is first time I used Github Please help me !! Thanks in advance

P/s: this error happen in this line:

```
#import <XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h>
```

Comment: `#import "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h"`, if your framework doesn't come in a `FrameworkName.framework` bundle.

Comment: This comment above is absolutely right. Thanks a ton.